# How to create graph pies with different sizes using bézier paths in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, graphic, quartz-core

I want to make a nice graphic pie with 8 equal slices, that can be individually scaled or resized depending on an Int or something like this. This would look something like below just that all the slices should be equally cut:

[image]

I have tried this in Objective-C but it makes just one slice:

```
  -(CAShapeLayer *)createPieSlice {
    CAShapeLayer *slice = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    slice.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    slice.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    slice.lineWidth = 3.0;

    CGFloat angle = DEG2RAD(-60.0);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);
    CGFloat radius = 100.0;

    UIBezierPath *piePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [piePath moveToPoint:center];

    [piePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + radius * cosf(angle), center.y + radius * sinf(angle))];

    [piePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:angle endAngle:DEG2RAD(60.0) clockwise:YES];

    //  [piePath addLineToPoint:center];
    [piePath closePath]; // this will automatically add a straight line to the center
    slice.path = piePath.CGPath;

    return slice;
    }
```

How can I achieve that graph in swift?

Comment: By mapping it out, figuring out the math, and writing code that implements that math. It's called programming. You should try it. (Sorry, I'm not going to do you work for you.)

Comment: I just posted a sample project that generates pie charts like the one you show in your question with both varying radius and slice width. Take a look. Its' a fully working application.

Comment: Very nice application, and way better than my solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break the problem into logical pieces.

You have wedges of different arc widths. All those radii need to add up to a full circle. I assume they represent fractions of something that adds up to 100%. Do you want a specific order? If so, map your fractions in the order you want, such that they all add up to 100%.

Then write code that starts at an angle of zero, and creates arcs that are the specified fraction of 2π. Each one would start at the end of the previous one. Assign a radius that's appropriate based on the data you need.

Now write code that creates closed path segments in a UIBezierPath.

### EDIT

You've clarified, and told us that you always want 8 slices of the same width but with different radii.

So you need to write code that takes 8 input values and plots it as 8 arcs with different radius values.

Let's say your input value is an array of floats ranging from 0 to 1. At zero, the wedge is zero-sized. At 1.0, it's the largest circle size that will fit in your view (half the width of a square view.

So you would create an array of 8 floats:

```
var fractions = [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0 .6, .2, .9]
```

The code to create a bezier curve with 8 arcs might look something like this:

```
let pi = 3.1415826
let largestRadius = myView.width/2

let piePath = UIBezierPath()
for (index, afloat) in fractions
{
  let startAngle = Double(index) / fractions.count * 2 * pi
  let endAngle = Double(index+1) / fractions.count * 2 * pi
  let thisRadius = largestRadius * afloat
  let center = CGPointMake( myView.width/2, myView.height/2)
  piePath.moveToPoint(center)
  
  piePath.addArcWithCenter(center,
    radius: thisRadius,
    startAngle: startAngle,
    endAngle: endAngle,
    clockwise: true)
  piePath.lineToPoint(center)
  piePath.closePath()
}
```

I **think** the code above would create 8 closed pie-slice paths, but I'm not positive. It might be necessary to add a lineToPoint call between the first moveToPoint call and the arc call.

### Edit #2:

Since I am learning Swift, I decided to take this as an exercise and wrote a sample project that generates pie charts using a shape layer and a a custom path created from a UIBezierPath, as outlined above. You can find the sample project on github: [PieCharts project on Github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/PieChart.git)

Comment: I'm not that good at math! The arc should always have the same radii because the pie is divided in 8 equal parts, that should be equal at the arc, but grow from center to exterior.

Comment: If you want to do computer graphics, you need to understand geometry and basic trig. There's no way around it.

Comment: You're wrong about the arcs always having the same radius. You show a graph where the pie slices are different radiuses, and different widths as well. Think pizza. Some of those slices are from a 16" pizza. Some are from a 14". Some are from 12", and some are from a 10" pizza. Then they are different fractions of each pizza. The biggest, brightest slice is about a 3rd of a 16" pizza. (The arc is about 1/3 of 2π, and it has a large radius. The smallest piece is maybe a 16th of a very small pizza.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it right. The graph should be similar to the image, but the slices of pizza are all 8 equal.

Comment: Equal in radius, or in arc angle? Radius is the size of the pizza. arc angle is the thickness of a slice. You can have a very thick slick of a very small pizza (small radius, large arc angle) , or a very thin slice of a very large pizza (large radius, small arc angle) or any combination. You've said before that the radius would always be the same, now you're saying that the arc angle would always be the same.

Comment: Yes, they must have the same arc angle, and they can be small slices, or any size of pizza but always the same arc angle.

Comment: See my edits. I added some sample code (not tested.)

Comment: I have tried the code you provided but with no success. Thanks very much for your help anyways!

Comment: The code I posted is not intended to simply compile and use. It's a rough sketch of how to do it. I'm pretty new to Swift, so it probably has syntax errors. You need to integrate it with your app, and then you'll need to get it to compile and debug it.

Comment: I have tried to integrate it with my app but I didn't manage to find a solution, but thanks for your interest! You're a good guy!

Comment: @eeschimosu, did you see my edit? I put a working demo program on Github that creates full pie charts.

Comment: yes and I accepted your answer! Super cool demo! Totally love it! Way smoother and efficient than what I tried! :)

Comment: Core Graphics doesn't usually work very smoothly for animation. Core Animation is almost always smoother, faster, and more CPU-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve my problem using Core Graphics! Thanks @duncan-c for your interest.

**EDIT:**
I have dropped my first solution in the favour of @duncan-c's solution, that works better for my needs!

```
import UIKit

class Pie: UIView {

     // In range of 0.0 to 1.0
    var endArc:CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

var arcWidth:CGFloat = 5.0
var arcColor = UIColor()
var arcBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
var arcStrokeColor = UIColor()
var startFloat:CGFloat = 0.0
var radius:CGFloat = 0.0
var radiusSize: CGFloat = 0.0

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // Important constants for circle
    let fullCircle = 2.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    let start:CGFloat = startFloat * fullCircle
    let end:CGFloat = endArc * fullCircle + start

    // Find the centerpoint of the rect
    var centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))

    // Set the radius
    radius = (radiusSize - arcWidth) / 2.0

    // Starting point for all drawing code is getting the context.
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Set colorspace
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    // Set line attributes
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, arcWidth)

    // Draw the pie
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, arcStrokeColor.CGColor)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, arcColor.CGColor)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y)
    CGContextAddArc(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, start, end, 0)
    CGContextFillPath(context)
}
}
```

And then subclassd the UIView where I needed using:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var graph: Pie!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let backgroundTrackColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let strokeColor = UIColor(white: 0.15, alpha: 1.0)

    graph.radiusSize = 50.0
    graph.arcBackgroundColor = backgroundTrackColor
    graph.arcStrokeColor = strokeColor
    graph.arcColor = UIColor.redColor()
    graph.startFloat = 0.750
    graph.arcWidth = 5.0
    graph.endArc = 0.125
}
```